# Call function from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I call function loadTable from another controller?

```
    app.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
       scope.loadTable = function() {
       //some code
       };
    });

    app.controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
       scope.buttonClick = function() {
       //call loadTable from tableCtrl
       };
    });
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468334/call-a-method-of-a-controller-from-another-controller-using-scope-in-angularjs

Comment: try with $rootScope and for more try to go through tutorial for $rootScope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$emit-$on`(publish-subscribe) mechanism.

```
app.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
    scope.loadTable = function() {
        //some code
    };

    $rootScope.$on('load-table', function (event, arg1, arg2) {
        // now trigger the method.
        scope.loadTable();
    });
});

app.controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
    scope.buttonClick = function() {
        //call loadTable from tableCtrl
        //emit the event
        $rootScope.$emit('load-table', 'arg1', 'arg2');
    };
});
```

Comment: Yep, I was trying to remember the syntax. This will do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps use a service such as

```
app.factory('tableService', [function () {

   return {
       loadTable : function() {
          //some code
       }
   };
});


app.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope', 'tableService', function (scope, tableService) {

});

app.controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', 'tableService', function (scope, tableService) {
   scope.buttonClick = function() {
       tableService.loadTable();
   };
});
```

Your tableCtrl would then need to save any data using another function on the service.