# AngularJS - Inter-controller function execution using events

Tags: angularjs

So I have 2 controllers in a module each of them has its own responsibilities, since I am making a real time function so I would need to keep both controller's data in sync if an action is being executed. I've came across angular's `$emit` and `$on` which it said that I can trigger a function by emitting an event. I've followed the instructions and guidelines on how to implement the triggers but somehow I cannot make it to work.

Basically what I wanted to do is, I have 2 controllers, `CtrlA` and `CtrlB`. Both of the controllers have many functions say `CtrlAactionA`, `CtrlAactionB`, `CtrlBactionA`, `CtrlBactionB`. According to some other guides in stackoverflow, given when `CtrlBactionB` in `CtrlB` is being called, it should at the same time triggers `CtrlAactionB` in `CtrlA` but I cannot managed to trigger such action. It will only execute `CtrlBactionB` in `CtrlB`.

```
app.controller('CtrlA', function($scope) {
  $scope.ctrlAdataA;
  $scope.ctrlAdataB = 0;

  $scope.ctrlAactionA = function (){
    $scope.ctrlAdataA = 'This is the original data.';
  }

  $scope.ctrlAactionB = function (){
    $scope.ctrlAdataA = 'Someone clicked the button in B so I changed!';
    $scope.ctrlAdataB++;
  }

  $scope.$on('buttonClicked', function(event, args) {
        $scope.ctrlAactionB();
    });
});

app.controller('CtrlB', function($scope) {
  $scope.ctrlBdataA;
  $scope.ctrlBdataB = 0;

  $scope.ctrlBactionA = function (){
    $scope.ctrlBdataA = 'I\'ve been clicked!';
    $scope.ctrlBdataB++;
    $scope.$emit('buttonClicked');
  }
});
```

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LdVxnEkZDL69uvNeoTj4?p=preview) file I made to simulate my described scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to implement events, you have to use $broadcast instead of $emit, and you have to do it from parent scope (i.e. $rootScope), since $broadcast dispatches events downwards. So in the CtrlB controller change this line:`$scope.$emit('buttonClicked');` with this one: `$rootScope.$broadcast('buttonClicked');`, and add $rootScope as a dependency in your CtrlB controller.

Here's a plunker with the change implemented

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/50hk7OOxq1J63SYPQPz1?p=preview)

The $emit wasn't working because $emit dispatches an event upwards, and it couldn't find the CtrlA there.
More info: [AngularJS Emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit)

Answer (score 0):

I found this related to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468749/5235299

Hope it ll help you a bit