# angular controllerAs(this) equivalent of $scope.$broadcast and $scope.on,

Tags: angularjs

According to this answer I just want fire event from controller to another

[Call a method of a controller from another controller using 'scope' in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468334/call-a-method-of-a-controller-from-another-controller-using-scope-in-angularjs)

```
$scope.$on("myEvent", function (event, args) {
   $scope.rest_id = args.username;
   $scope.getMainCategories();
});
```

And in the second controller you'd just do

```
$scope.initRestId = function(){
   $scope.$broadcast("myEvent", {username: $scope.user.username });
};
```

But I don't use $scope in my application, just controllerAs and this. There is a way to fire event without inject the scope ? Or should I inject $scope anyway ?But I read in another answer that using both scope and controllerAs is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to register an `$emit` or `$broadcast` event without `$scope` or `$rootScope` being injected in the controller.

It is indeed bad practice to use `$scope` variables and functions since the instance of your controller is already injected inside the `$scope` with the `controllerAs` syntax.

But there is not other choice than injecting scope objects if you want to use these events.

However you shouldn't use `$emit` or `$broadcast` events just to share data. These events are used for application wide information (like user has logged in or logged out...etc.)

A good practice when using angular events is to prefer `$rootScope.$emit` because `$scope` relies on the hierarchy of your components.

For example:

`$scope.$emit` will emit to the parent component.

`$scope.$broadcast` will broadcast to children components.

Then `$rootScope.$broadcast` will broadcast events to the rootScope as well as the scope (which may make your code messy real quick)

`$rootScope.$emit` is to be preferred as it registers the event application wide and makes it available to the rootScope only. (`$rootScope.$on`)

Another good practice is to unbind your custom events.
Whenever a component or directive is unloaded/destroyed, the event listener will still reside inside rootScope resulting in possible memory leaks.

To unbind an event:

```
var unbind = $rootScope.$on('logout', function(event, data) {
    console.log('LOGOUT', data);
});
$scope.$on('$destroy', unbind);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that generally overuse of $broadcast and $emit is a bad practice too. If you don't want to use the $scope, why not moving the logic handled by events to a service?

Comment: I use service, but anyway when MyController2 of view2 is changing state, I want MyController1 to update for refresh view1. And Controller2 can't know about service value change, unless i use $watch or $broadcast to fire event so i back to my question :p