# Implement a single method or use $scope.on and $scope.emit in AngularJs that will call the same method in multiple controllers without a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, emit

I know similar questions has been asked in the past, but I hope to get a better understanding to my specific issue.

I have multiple `controllers` managing the `view` of a single page. The main reason for this is that the functionality of each `controller` is vastly different, and I also combined some functionality that used to be on separate `views`. This is also not an issue that will be resolved by creating a `service`. I only need to "kick-start" both `controllers`.

**This is my question:** I want to implement a single `date filter/method` on the `view`, that will call the same `method` in both `controllers` to do its functionality, and update the `view` accordingly.

**EDIT: How can I use `$scope.on` and `$scope.emit`, or `$rootScope` to call the function in both `controllers`?**

As per these previously posted questions:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468334/call-a-method-of-a-controller-from-another-controller-using-scope-in-angularjs)

**Here are the two `controllers`:**

```
angular.module('portalDashboardApp')
  .controller('SocialMentionsAnalysisController', SocialMentionsAnalysisController);

angular.module('portalDashboardApp')
  .controller('SocialMentionsListController', SocialMentionsListController);
```

**This is the `method` call in my single `view`:**

```
ng-change="checkDate()
```

**This is the `filter method` that gets called:**

**NOTE:** Each of the `controllers` has this `method`, and I would like to call both these `methods` via my `single method call`.

```
$scope.checkDate = function () {

    var dateValues = DatePickerService.checkDate($scope.dateFrom, $scope.dateTo);
    $scope.dateFrom = dateValues[0];
    $scope.dateTo = dateValues[1];
    $sessionStorage.dateFrom = dateValues[0];
    $sessionStorage.dateTo = dateValues[1];

    pullSocialData();

};
```

I have done research, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-controller-in-the-same-module?rq=1) is perhaps what I need, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the $on functions with same name will get called with its corresponding single $emit call. I mean, you have multiple $on functions in multiple controllers,

```
$scope.$on('funtionToTrigger', function(event, args) {
//in first controller
});

$scope.$on('funtionToTrigger', function(event, args) {
//in second controller
});

$scope.$on('funtionToTrigger', function(event, args) {
//in third controller
});
```

Note: all $on functions' name are same 'funtionToTrigger'.
Once you call `$scope.$emit('funtionToTrigger', args);` then all three $on functions will run in all three controllers.

So here, you have write a $on function in each controller.

```
function SocialMentionsAnalysisController () {
    $scope.$on('funtionToTrigger', function(event, dateFrom, dateTo) {
    //your code for this controller.
    });
}

function SocialMentionsListController() {
    $scope.$on('funtionToTrigger', function(event, dateFrom, dateTo) {
    //your code for this controller.
    });
}
```

Then call $emit on `onChange`.

```
ng-change="$emit('funtionToTrigger', dateFrom, dateTo)"
```

Comment: Hi Amir, thank you fior the great answer. I have a question; can I add the `$emit` to the function like this: `ng-change="checkDate(); $emit("activate")"` to call this: `$scope.$on("activate", function (event, args) {pullSocialData();});`?

Comment: I have set it up as follow: in my date `directive`:`ng-model="dateFrom" ng-change="$emit('dateChanged', dateFrom, dateTo); checkDate()"`, and like this in my `controller`: `$scope.$on("dateChanged", function checkdate(event, dateFrom, dateTo) {var dateValues = DatePickerService.checkDate(dateFrom, dateTo); pullSocialData(); })` This almost works. My `$scope.$on method` gets called in the 1st `controller`, but not in my second `controller`. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no parent relation between scope's controllers. You need to emit event from $rootScope

Comment: Would I simply inject $rootScope, and change the $scope.on to $rootScope.on?

Comment: I changed it to $rootScope, and it works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understand correctly the question but you can use directive for this. Instead of use ng-change, you can create your own directive that bin on change of input and check the date here.

For example, your javascript :

```
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) { })
   .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) { })
   .directive('checkDate', function(checkDateService) {
      return {
         restrict: 'A',
         scope: true,
         link: function(scope, element, attrs ){
           element.on('change', function() {
             scope.$apply(function() {
               checkDateService.checkDate(scope.from, scope.to);
             })
         });
    }
  }
 }).service('checkDateService', function() {
   return {
     checkDate: function(from, to) {
     console.log(from, to);
   }
 }
```

});

And the HTML :

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <input type="date" ng-model="from" check-date />
    <input type="date" ng-model="to" check-date />
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <input type="date" ng-model="from" check-date />
    <input type="date" ng-model="to" check-date />
  </div>
</body>
```

Here the same sample as plunker :https://plnkr.co/edit/Jqz7Zd4HF0WVBvkJHBbZ?p=preview

To use event in inline js on HTML, I think you can define a methode on $rootScope (at run configuration) that broadcast your event. This event will be triggered by all controller depends on $rootScope.

In Javascript :

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
   $rootScope.brodcastDateChanged = function(dateFrom, dateTo) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('dateChanged', {
         from: dateFrom,
         to: dateTo
      });
    };
})
.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) { 
    $scope.$on('dateChanged', function(event, args) {
        console.log('event triggered from Ctrl1', args)
    });
 })
 .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {  
    $scope.$on('dateChanged', function(event, args) {
         console.log('event triggered from Ctrl2', args)
    });
  })
  .controller('Ctrl3', function($scope) {  
     $scope.$on('dateChanged', function(event, args) {
         console.log('event triggered from Ctrl3', args)
     });
   })
```

In HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
  <input type="date" ng-model="from" ng-change="brodcastDateChanged(from, to)" />
  <input type="date" ng-model="to" ng-change="brodcastDateChanged(from, to)" />
</div>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
  <input type="date" ng-model="from" ng-change="brodcastDateChanged(from, to)" />
  <input type="date" ng-model="to" ng-change="brodcastDateChanged(from, to)" />
</div>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
  <input type="date" ng-model="from" ng-change="brodcastDateChanged(from, to)" />
  <input type="date" ng-model="to" ng-change="brodcastDateChanged(from, to)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Silvinus. Thank you for the response and great input. I am in fact already making use of a `directive` for the dates. The issue with this is that both the dates (one in each `controller HTML`) doesn't get changed automatically or at the same time. One will still have to change each date for each part of the view controlled by each `controller`. Any thoughts?

Comment: If I transpose your comment in my sample, You want change the date from of Ctrl2 when date from of Ctrl1 change and vice versa?

Comment: I am actually trying to call a function in each controller when the data in ctrl 1 changes. I am trying $emit and $scope.$on, but only 2 of the 3 controllers are effected. I think the $emit gets destroyed or something.