# Can we call the function inside the controller from another controller of another file in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call a function inside a controller which is in another controller inside another js file.

I have tried `$broadcast` and `$emit` but I think it works only inside the same file.

I have a controller called `videoWidgetController` which has the function named `clickVideoWidgetListItemFromDOM`.

I need to call it from my another controller named `videoController`.

In this file, I am calling the function on click event like `data-ng-click="clickVideoWidgetListItemFromDOM(video, $index)"`

***videoController***

```
$scope.clickVideoWidgetListItem = function(video, index) {  
    $scope.$emit("myEvent"); *** didn't work for me ***
    $rootScope.$broadcast("myEvent", {video: video,index: index }); *** didn't work for me ***  
};
```

***videoWidgetController***

```
$scope.$on("myEvent", function (event, args) {
    alert(1);
    console.log(args);
   $scope.clickVideoWidgetListItemFromDOM();
});
```

I was trying as mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468334/call-a-method-of-a-controller-from-another-controller-using-scope-in-angularjs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but, couldn't get the solution.

I searched a lot but unfortunately still in the same problem.

Comment: Why not just factor out the common parts of the two controllers into another file?

Comment: $rootScope.$broadcast should definitely work . not sure why it didnt.Do they belong to same module?

Comment: [`$emit` emits it UP, to parents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28156845/8495123), which in your case can only be the global scope - `$rootScope`, so you need to transmit it with `$rootScope.$emit("myEvent")` and listen with `$rootScope.$on`.

Comment: This almost certainly means that your code is poorly structured. Try to take a step back and spilt the code into smaller logical components.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a broadcast-emit data transfer to happen, the following condition must be satisfied

> The event is to be broadcasted from the parent controller, and the
>   event is to be listened from the child controller. Broadcast method id
>   used to transfer data from parent to child.

If this hierarchy does not work, you can transfer data by [services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856153/how-can-i-pass-some-data-from-one-controller-to-another-peer-controller).

Comment: I don't have this hierarchy these two are totally separate controllers. What should I do for that?